# Name and influence of style used for futuristic line patterns?

Tags: color, line-drawing, refraction

What is the name of the style of the line graphics used in the image below? The line patterns seem to envelope the shape of the woman maybe algorithmically somehow, becoming denser and yellow on the chest.

Are there other artists that employ this technique, or where it was borrowed from?

Besides the line patterns, the coloring of the lines gives a holographic sort of feeling. Is there also a distinct style name for the coloring scheme used for the lines?

Any ideas overall on which software and computer graphics/machine learning techniques were used to create the line patterns and colors?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That looks a lot like it’s based on the [straight skeleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Straight_skeleton) of some outline shapes drawn on the image. You can see similar structures in the middle one of these diagrams from [a research page](https://www.sthu.org/research/straightskeleton/) by Stefan Huber, one of the researchers who’s published a lot of work on straight skeletons:
[image: a series of images of Tux, the Linux penguin mascot, one with skeletal patterns overlaid and one with isocontours derived from those patterns]

Comment: how about the additional quirks that appear to be leaf-like fractals? and how the intensity/denseness of the pattern warms to a brighter color

Comment: The extra details at the edges most likely come from irregularities in the outline—the more complex the edge of the shape, the more lines will make up the edge of its skeleton. As best I can tell, the pattern itself is drawn in three flat colors (orange, yellow, green), generated from three different sets of shapes; the variation in the colors is from some blending operation being used to draw the pattern on top of the original image.

Comment: which softwares were likely used to draw the straight skeleton lines that appear in the image?

Comment: That’s a good question; I’m afraid I have no idea. If you’re looking for a tool to do something similar, other good keywords to start a search with would be “topological skeleton” or “medial axis”.